# Disable submit button once the user submits the form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am using the PHP & MySQL to submit a form with following code and using `isset` function in PHP to submit the value to database.

```
<div class="display">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required="required">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Mobile" required="required" onblur="check();">
            <br/>
            <span id="e_mobile"></span>
            <?php if(isset($_GET["r"])){ ?><p>Invalid number; must be ten digits. Please submit your query again</p><?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="landline" id="landline" placeholder="Alternate Number" required="required" onblur="check1();">
            <br/>
            <span id="e_landline"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Your Address" required="required">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" value="0" name="salesid"/>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
</div>
```

Now I want once the user click submit button once the button should freeze; as of now if the user clicks the submit button more than once(by intentionally or by mistake) the same information is getting submitted in the database more than once.

What to do in this circumstance?

Comment: use attribute called disabled for this scenario....

Comment: This will do what you are asking `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript: this.disabled = true;"/>` but I don't think this is the way should handle this situation (Preventing form re-submitting).

Answer (score 0):

Try with JQuery:

First add an ID to your form

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
```

After that add script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function(e){
        $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled","disabled");
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add PHP Captcha to prevent user click again.

Please review below two urls which includes demo too.

1. http://www.w3schools.in/php/captcha/
2. http://99webtools.com/blog/php-simple-captcha-script/